# How to create an dynamic input list without creating a db collection

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to build a form in which you can dynamically add text inputs as required.  I don't want to save anything until the person clicks 'save' so it's important that this is done without a db collection.

I came up with this solution (http://meteorpad.com/pad/zP8EGjigXASfFrXsF/Input%20Test) but I'm unsure if this is the correct approach or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most users probably don't need to directly use `Tracker.Dependency` anymore because there are now higher-level options that are are a bit easier to use. Here are two choices:

### Client Collections

You can declare a client-side collection like:

```
InputOptions = new Mongo.Collection(null);
```

It will have all of the same behavior as a normal collection without trying to sync its data to the server. This is probably what you want. The only disadvantage is that the collection will be available to your whole application, so its reactivity is not isolated to a single template.

### ReactiveVar

You can use either a [ReactiveVar](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg) or a [ReactiveDict](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict) and [scope it to your template](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity). This is a bit better than directly using `Tracker.Dependency` because you don't have to call `changed` all over the place. Overall the syntax is more cumbersome that a client-side collection, but you get the advantage of isolating the reactivity if you need more than one of them.

Comment: Thanks man - that's a big help.  One aspect that still makes me sway towards a Tracker is my need to have an 'index' for each of the text inputs.  For instance, if I store the index on the client-side collection then when the user removes a given input I don't want to have to go through and update all the indexes in the collection.  The way I'm currently doing this is via the "all" reactive method in my code - it does a map and returns objects with the index of the array.  If Meteor just provided a way to have get the index of a each loop I would be a lot easier.

Comment: Yeah, you *could* use a ReactiveVar that only contains your `inputs` array. The downside is that you'll have to `get` and `set` it every time you make a change which may not end up being fewer lines of code.

Comment: Yeah, I thought as much.  Thanks for your help.